# Display array items in one td with each item on a new line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array from a `datatable` populating a table in my Bootstrap modal.

When displayed in the modal it displays as the below:

[image]

This is my current jQuery to populate my table in my modal:

```
$('#selectedReportDataTable').on('click', 'button[name="deleteContentButton"]', function () {
    var deleteRunData = selectedReportDataTable.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();

    $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
    $('span[name=selectedReport').text(reportSelectedLowerCased);
    $('td[name=modalPeriod]').text(deleteRunData.period);
    $('td[name=modalSpecParams]').text(deleteRunData.specialParams);
    $('td[name=modalFreq]').text(deleteRunData.frequency);
    $('td[name=modalTimeFrame]').text(deleteRunData.timeFrame);
    $('td[name=modalTime]').text(deleteRunData.time);
    $('td[name=modalRecipients]').text(deleteRunData.recipient);

    $('#deleteModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#deleteModalNoButton').focus();
    });
})
```

It's the last line:

```
$('td[name=modalRecipients]').text(deleteRunData.recipient);
```

that populating the email column

This is the code I have tried:

```
var abc = deleteRunData.recipient
var def = deleteRunData.recipient.toString().split(", ").join("<br/>");
var ghi = $('td[name=modalRecipients]').text();
var jkl = def.replace(/,/g, "\n")

console.log(abc)
console.log(def)
console.log(ghi)
console.log(jkl)

console.log(abc.join('\r\n'));
```

and this gives me the following:

[image]

If I replace:

```
$('td[name=modalRecipients]').text(deleteRunData.recipient);
```

with the following (as an example):

```
$('td[name=modalRecipients]').text(def.replace(/,/g, "\n"));
```

It looks like the below:

[image]

It's replaced the comma with a space, not what I was after. I want each entry on a new line - what am I doing wrong?

HTML just in case:

```
<table class="table" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <th class="modalTable" style="width: 50px">Period</th>
        <th class="modalTable" style="width: 85px">Additional details</th>
        <th class="modalTable" style="width: 55px">Frequency</th>
        <th class="modalTable" style="width: 45px">Time frame</th>
        <th class="modalTable" style="width: 25px">Time</th>
        <th class="modalTable">Recipient(s)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td name="modalPeriod" class="modalTable"></td>
        <td name="modalSpecParams" class="modalTable"></td>
        <td name="modalFreq" class="modalTable"></td>
        <td name="modalTimeFrame" class="modalTable"></td>
        <td name="modalTime" class="modalTable"></td>
        <td name="modalRecipients" class="modalTable" style="word-wrap: break-word"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

God dam it. Soon as i hit submit the answer came instantly using the below code

```
for (var i = 0; i < deleteRunData.recipient.length; i++) {
    $('td[name=modalRecipients]').append('<div>' + deleteRunData.recipient[i] + '</div>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should replace `$('td[name=modalRecipients]').text(def.replace(/,/g, "\n"));` with `$('td[name=modalRecipients]').html(def.replace(/,/g, "<br \/>")`

[try this](https://codepen.io/wenjoy/pen/oNvdWOd?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

**edit:-** rightt well i started this reply before the accepted answer came but i thought i would put it here in-case it other people run into this and need helps.

**Original Answer**

Totally understand the code blindness, especially with divs and css because this is the most fustrating and angry part of coding the backends! As I understand it, you are looking for multiple emails to display in the email column. So as an example, if there were two recipients, tony@tony.com and crisps@cristony.com, then we would expect

tony@tony.com
crisps@cristony.com

NOTE: NO COMMAS INBETNWNEN THE EMAILS.

When I come across this problem, normally I would write the following code in javascripts

```
for (var i = 0; i < deleteRunData.recipient.length; i++) {
    $('td[name=modalRecipients]').append('<div>' + deleteRunData.recipient[i] + 
    '</div>');
}
```

Thsi works some of the time when the deleteRunData exists, if it does not then we have a problem!! Sometimes it does not exist because the people who coded the front ends who we are relying on (server guys), don't make this!! In the case of when deleteRunData does not exist, what I do is create an image of all possible combinations of emails with new lines!!

so for example, for your example i would make a jpeg image of the two emails on photoshops or paintshopro, then i would do

```
$('td[name=modalRecipients]').append('<img src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato_chip#/media/File:Potato-Chips.jpg" width="500" height="600">')
```

works for me.

just two extra things that i have come across after regianing my sight

1. why is tony@test.com receiving five emails about their evening call costs? I would have thought one would suffice?
   2.jquery is known to be dangerous when mixed with css and php-sass. please make sure its the rite back end technology for your use case!

hope this helps